# Error: RefNonZero When Returning a Uniue_Ptr to ClientReader in GRPC

Tags: c++, pointers, grpc

After defining a method of the following form:

```
std::unique_ptr<ClientReader<FlowCellPositionResponse> > method(FlowCellPositionsRequest request) 
{
   ...
   ClientContext context;
   return stub->some_method(&context, request); // Also tried std::move
}
```

within a file and accessing this method via another file's method like so:

```
FlowCellPositionsRequest request;
FlowCellPositionsResponse response;
std::unique_ptr<ClientReader<FlowCellPositionResponse> > reader = file.method(request);
while(reader->Read(&response)) { // Error raised here
   ...
}
Status status = reader->Finish();
```

I get the following error:

```
Assertion failed: (prior > 0), function RefNonZero, file ref_counted.h, line 119.
[1]    2450 abort      ./program
```

If I move this logic back into `method`, it runs fine, but I wanted to create this abstraction. I'm still quite new to both C++ and GRPC and I was just wondering what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `ClientContext` is going out of scope when `method()` returns, but that object needs to outlive the `ClientReader<>` object that you're returning.

I think what you probably want here is an object to hold all of the state needed for the RPC, including both the `ClientContext` and the `ClientReader<>`.  Then you can return that object from `method()`.